# Regression with equality and inequality constrained coefficients in R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, regression

I am trying to obtain estimated constrained coefficients using RSS.  The beta coefficients are constrained between [0,1] and sum to 1.  Additionally, my third parameter is constrained between (-1,1).  Utilizing the below I can obtain a nice solution using simulated variables but when implementing the methodology on my real data set I keep arriving at a non-unique solution.  In turn, I'm wondering if there is a more numerically stable way to obtain my estimated parameters.

```
set.seed(234)
k = 2
a = diff(c(0, sort(runif(k-1)), 1))
n = 1e4
x = matrix(rnorm(k*n), nc = k)
a2 = -0.5
y = a2 * (x %*% a) + rnorm(n)
f = function(u){sum((y - u[3] * (x %*% u[1:2]))^2)}
g = function(v){

v1 = v[1]
v2 = v[2]
u = vector(mode = "double", length = 3)

# ensure in (0,1)
v1 = 1 / (1 + exp(-v1))

# ensure add up to 1
u[1:2] = c(v1, 1 - sum(v1))

# ensure between [-1,1]
u[3] = (v2^2 - 1) / (v2^2 + 1)
u
}

res = optim(rnorm(2), function(v) f(g(v)), hessian = TRUE, method = "BFGS")
eigen(res$hessian)$values
res$convergence
rbind(Est = res$par, SE = sqrt(diag(solve(res$hessian))))
rbind(g(res$par),c(a,a2))
```

Hats off to http://zoonek.free.fr/blosxom/R/2012-06-01_Optimization.html

Comment: When https://stackoverflow.com/users/1129973/vincent-zoonekynd illustrated sum-to-one constraints on htat page, he used `quadprog`. Maybe he will show up and give you a hand.

Comment: @42- very helpful

Comment: @user5087936 Please take a look at my example below on how to implement a model with constrained parameter in Stan/RStan. It'd be interesting to know how the model performs on your real data.

Answer (score 1):

Since there has been no direct answer to your question so far, I'd like to show a way how to implement a parameter-constrained model in [Stan/RStan](http://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstan). You should give this a try using your real data.

Doing Bayesian inference has the advantage of giving you posterior probabilities for your (constrained) model parameters. Point estimates including confidence intervals can then be easily calculated.

1. First off, we load the library and set RStan to store the compiled model and use multiple cores (if available).

   ```
   library(rstan);
   rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE);
   options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores());
   ```
2. We now define our Stan model. In this case, it's very simple, and we can make use of RStan's `simplex` data type for vectors of non-negative values that sum to one.

   ```
   model <- "
   data {
       int<lower=1> n;   // number of observations
       int<lower=0> k;   // number of parameters
       matrix[n, k] X;   // data
       vector[n] y;      // response
   }

   parameters {
       real a2;          // a2 is a free scaling parameter
       simplex[k] a;     // a is constrained to sum to 1
       real sigma;       // residuals
   }

   model {
       // Likelihood
       y ~ normal(a2 * (X * a), sigma);
   }"
   ```

   Stan supports various constrained data types; I'd recommend taking a lot at the [Stan manual](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.17.0/stan-reference-2.17.0.pdf) for more complex examples.
3. Using the sample data from your original question, we can run our model:

   ```
   # Sample data
   set.seed(234);
   k = 2;
   a = diff(c(0, sort(runif(k-1)), 1));
   n = 1e4;
   x = matrix(rnorm(k * n), nc = k);
   a2 = -0.5;
   y = a2 * (x %*% a) + rnorm(n);

   # Fit stan model
   fit <- stan(
       model_code = model,
       data = list(
           n = n,
           k = k,
           X = x,
           y = as.numeric(y)),
       iter = 4000,
       chains = 4);
   ```

   Running the model will only take a few seconds (after the parser has internally translated and compiled the model in C++), and the full results (posterior distributions for all parameters conditional on the data) are stored in `fit`.
4. We can inspect the contents of `fit` using `summary`:

   ```
   # Extract parameter estimates
   pars <- summary(fit)$summary;
   pars;
   #               mean      se_mean          sd          2.5%           25%
   #a2       -0.4915289 1.970327e-04 0.014363398    -0.5194985    -0.5011471
   #a[1]      0.7640606 2.273282e-04 0.016348488     0.7327691     0.7527457
   #a[2]      0.2359394 2.273282e-04 0.016348488     0.2040952     0.2248482
   #sigma     1.0048695 8.746869e-05 0.007048116     0.9909698     1.0001889
   #lp__  -5048.4273105 1.881305e-02 1.204892294 -5051.4871931 -5048.9800451
   #                50%           75%         97.5%    n_eff      Rhat
   #a2       -0.4916061    -0.4819086    -0.4625947 5314.196 1.0000947
   #a[1]      0.7638723     0.7751518     0.7959048 5171.881 0.9997468
   #a[2]      0.2361277     0.2472543     0.2672309 5171.881 0.9997468
   #sigma     1.0048994     1.0095420     1.0187554 6492.930 0.9998086
   #lp__  -5048.1238783 -5047.5409682 -5047.0355381 4101.832 1.0012841
   ```

   You can see that `a[1]+a[2]=1`.

   Plotting parameter estimates including confidence intervals is also easy:

   ```
   plot(fit);
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve optimization problems with equality *and* inequality constraints will most likely be through the "augmented Lagrangian" approach. In R this is, for example, realized in the *alabama* package.

```
# function and gradient
fn = function(u){sum((y - u[3] * (x %*% u[1:2]))^2)}
gr = function(u) numDeriv::grad(fn, u)

# constraint sum(u) == 1
heq = function(u) sum(u) - 1
# constraints 0 <= u[1],u[2] <= 1; -1 <= u[3] <= 1
hin = function(u) c(u[1], u[2], 1-u[1], 1-u[2], u[3]+1, 1-u[3])

sol_a = alabama::auglag(c(0.5, 0.5, 0), fn, gr, hin=hin, heq=heq)
sol_a
## $par
## [1]  1.0000000  0.3642904 -0.3642904
## $value
## [1] 10094.74
## ...
## $hessian
##             [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
## [1,] 15009565054  9999999977  9999992926
## [2,]  9999999977 10000002578  9999997167
## [3,]  9999992926  9999997167 10000022569
```

For other packages containing an "augmented Lagrangian" procedure see the CRAN Task View on optimization.