# Running Regression with Constraints on Coefficients

Tags: r, regression

Suppose I want to run a regression of the variable Y on x1, x2, and x3 in R. I want to constrain the coefficients to be greater than or equal to 0 and to sum to 1. I can't quite figure out how to do this, other than rewriting the OLS function and directly imposing the constraints. Some other answers discuss the optimize function, though the asker's questions were a bit different from mine.

I was hoping, also, to take this a step further and run a 2-stage least squares regression where I constrain several of the instruments in the same way, consistent with economic theory. Would this method be similar to the above?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Some of the [**these links**](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS550US551&ei=snWxWr20IsXUjwOUvacQ&q=R+regression+with+constraints&oq=R+regression+with+constraints&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1l2.1346.1346.0.1609.1.1.0.0.0.0.90.90.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.89....0.YNVsq7i1YCU) might be helpful.

Comment: I looked at many of these, but unfortunately none seem to quite meet the constraints I'm trying to impose. (Or, if they do, I haven't been able to decipher this after extensive searching and trial runs.)

Comment: I would suggest using `rstan`/`Stan` for this kind of problem. I've written up a little example for a different question, I would recommend taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816646/6530970). This should be highly relevant (and your question a potential duplicate). In the example, I impose the following constraint on the two model parameters in a simple linear regression model: `a[1] + a[2] = 1`.