# Constrained regression/optimization in R with boundedness, inequality, and equality constraints

Tags: r, optimization, regression

I have a dataset of overall performance rankings (`Y`) and a set of criteria used in computing said rankings (**`X`**) for a list of businesses.  I also have some limited information about the weights (**`b`**) being assigned to those criteria when computing the overall ranking.  Specifically, I know that:

- Only criterion `X1` receives full weight (`b1 = 1`) when the rankings are computed
- All other criteria are weighted at `0 < b < 1`
- Other relational (in)equalities apply to the weights for the other parameters.  For this example, let's assume the following constraints also apply:

  - `b3 < b2`
  - `b4 = b5`
- My dataset has `N` observations in it and, accordingly, `1 <= Y <= N`
- Ties exist

I know this lends itself to some form of constrained regression or quadratic optimization, but the other threads dealing with this borrow from examples with fewer constraints and are thus more easily programmed/solved.  Here are some of the threads I've already consulted:

[Regression with equality and inequality constrained coefficients in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776540/regression-with-equality-and-inequality-constrained-coefficients-in-r)

[constrained optimization R: another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451527/constrained-optimization-r-another-example)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19792/constrained-optimization-library-for-equality-and-inequality-constraints

**TL;DR**

How can I program and solve for a constrained optimization problem where:

- one coefficient equals 1
- all other coefficients are bounded between 0 and 1
- multiple inequality and equality constraints define the relationships between multiple combinations of coefficients

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you first need to decide which algorithm you want and then people can try to help with implementing the said algorithm. In terms of the algorithm, you could look at direct methods e.g. generalized reduced-gradient; complex method; Zoutendijk (1960) or indirect methods e.g. slac variables, penalty functions.

Comment: nls can handle bounds on coefficients. The CVXR package can handle general convex optimization problems.  The CRAN Optimization Task View lists numerous optimization packages for R.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: Thanks for the sound recommendations.  Exactly what I was looking for!  Also, I had no idea that [Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) lists were even a thing.  Very useful.